# How to profile building an android kotlin project verbosely?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, profiling, kapt

I have an android kotlin project, incremental build time of which is really huge. If I press `Make project`, wait till build complete and press `Make project` again, then it takes ~50 seconds to build, although I didn't make any change.
The --profile gradle option reveals that `:app:kaptDebugKotlin` and `:app:processDebugResources` take the most time(each one takes ~20sec).
How can I determine what is the cause of that? Btw. here is my gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
org.gradle.daemon=true
kotlin.incremental=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: Can you also provide your Gradle and Kotlin version?

Comment: @AndrzejZabost gradle-4.4 and kotlin-'1.2.31'. As for my gradle.build files I only use `implementation`, `kapt` and `compileOnly` instructions to declare dependencies, so I don't use `api`. Versions of depenencies are all exactly defined without `+` in them. Offline build doesn't make any difference